# Scheduled WebScraper that inserts into Google Calendar

Tags: java, google-calendar-api

I have written a webscraper in java that collects events from a site. I want to insert these events into **MY** google calendar. The webscraping functionality is there but I need help with the google calendar part... There are so many options of consuming a google api and I do not know which one to choose for my use case. I want the program to run on startup on my computer. Do I need a service account for this? What is the best approach?

Comment: Why not just expose a iCal location containing what you found?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Maybe that is an easy solution, but I have to admit I do not know anything about what you are suggesting, could you elaborate please